# Riak ReferenceError - with custom javascript

Tags: java, javascript, client, riak

i am playing around a litle with riak an the riak-java-client.

Now i run into trouble with custom javascript, i want to use in a map reduce query.

If i use the pure javascript functions as anon functions, they work well.

So here is what i did:

uncommented in app.conf

```
{js_source_dir, "/tmp/js_source"},
```

then i stored mylib.js in /tmp/js_source

```
/* content of mylib.js */
var NS = (function() {
    return {
        mapHighValues: function(value, keydata, arg) {
            var data = JSON.parse(value.values[0].data);
            ejsLog('/tmp/map_reduce.log', JSON.stringify(data.High));
             return [data.High];}
        },
        reduceSumHighValues: function(values) {
            ejsLog('/tmp/map_reduce.log', "ReduceVals\n" + JSON.stringify(values));
            return [values.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array) {return prev + curr} ,0)];
        }
    }
})();
```

after that i restarted riak.

Here is the relevant java code:

```
MapReduceBuilder builder = new MapReduceBuilder(new RiakClient("localhost"))
    .setBucket("goog")
    .map(JavascriptFunction.named("NS.mapHighValues"), false)
    .reduce(JavascriptFunction.named("NS.reduceSumHighValues"), true);
MapReduceResponseSource response = builder.submit();
```

Does anyone see my mistake?

Cheers

ApeHanger

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an extra '}' after 'return [data.High];'